# vsftpd : 500 OOPS: cannot read config file: 127.0.0.1

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd on my CentOS VM

```
rpm -qa | grep vsftp    
vsftpd-2.2.2-13.el6_6.1.x86_64

vsftpd is running     
service vsftpd status    
vsftpd (pid 14806) is running...
```

But I am unable to do ftp localhost or vsftpd 127.0.0.1 and it says

```
[root@ash-dev-xxx-admintest-01 vsftpd]#  vsftpd 127.0.0.1    
500 OOPS: cannot read config file: 127.0.0.1
```

Attached below is the vsftpd.conf file .

```
[root@ash-dev-xxx-admintest-01 vsftpd]# pwd    
/etc/vsftpd    
[root@ash-dev-xxx-admintest-01 vsftpd]# ls -l    
total 20    
-rw------- 1 root root  125 Oct 17  2014 ftpusers    
-rw------- 1 root root  361 Oct 17  2014 user_list    
-rw------- 1 root root 4597 Apr 28 06:10 vsftpd.conf    
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  338 Oct 17  2014 vsftpd_conf_migrate.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`vsftpd` is a service (`man vsftpd`) vsftpd - Very Secure FTP Daemon:

```
/sbin/service vsftpd status

vsftpd (pid 12870) is running...
```

If you stop it:

```
/sbin/service vsftpd stop
```

You won't be able to ftp to the server:

```
ftp 127.0.0.1

ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

Start the service again:

```
/sbin/service vsftpd start

Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                                [  OK  ]
```

Use **ftp** instead of **vsftpd** to connect to localhost....

```
# ftp 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (127.0.0.1:root):
```

Comment: no that did not answer my question. I have the service running.

Comment: [root@sea-dev-mms-admintest-01 vsftpd]# /sbin/service vsftpd status    
    vsftpd (pid 14806) is running...    
    [root@sea-dev-mms-admintest-01 vsftpd]# /sbin/service vsftpd stop    
Shutting down vsftpd:                                      [  OK  ]
[root@sea-dev-mms-admintest-01 vsftpd]# /sbin/service vsftpd start
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                                [  OK  ]
[root@sea-dev-mms-admintest-01 vsftpd]# vsftpd 127.0.0.1
500 OOPS: cannot read config file: 127.0.0.1

Comment: The trick here is that you use FTP and not VSFTPD to connect.  `vsftpd IP Address` is incorrect. `ftp IP Address` is the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it myself. I installed vsftpd but did not install the ftp client.
I installed ftp-0.17-54.el6.x86_64 and it solved the problem